# Duality functor is equivalence of category

Tags: functional-analysis, commutative-algebra, category-theory, representation-theory, frobenius-method

I am reading a book on Frobenius algebra in which I read all the following definitions:

Given a linear map $f:V\to W$ the dual map is defined by $f^{*}:W^{*}\to V^{*}$( as, $h\to f\circ h$)

Let there be a pairing $\beta:V \otimes W \to \mathbb{k}$ for each fix $w\in W$ define the linear functional $\beta_{w}:V \to \mathbb{k}$ as, $(v \to <v|w>)$. Now define

$\beta_{left}:W \to V^{*}$ given by $w\to \beta_{w}$ similarly define $\beta_{right}:V \to W^{*}$ given by $v\to \beta_{v}$  ( where, $\beta_{v}:W \to \mathbb{k}$ as, $(w \to <v|w>)$. After all these a paragraph in my book says as follows:

Actual question: For finite-dimensional vector spaces, the dualising functor is a (contravariant) equivalence of categories, so in particular it preserves the property of being invertible. So in this case $\beta_{left}$ is injective if and only if $\beta_{right}$ is.

I tried to prove the both the assertion but could not. Say for second assertion I assume $\beta_{left}$ is injective then how to proceed further I wanted to use $\ker(\beta_{left})=e$ but I dont know what is this $e$ as a functional.

Please help me by giving a solution/hint or a reference book that teaches Frobenius algebra in detailed way.

Comment: Assuming your $\beta$ is $v\otimes w\mapsto \langle v\mid w\rangle$.  It should be $\beta_{left}$ is *injective* iff $\beta_{right}$ is *surjective*, and vice versa.  This is probably first year linear algebra: either you note that $\beta_{left}$ and $\beta_{right}$ are basically dual map of each other, or you can do it the long way (suppose $\beta_{left}$ is surjective, then for every $v\neq 0$ there is some $\phi\in V^*$ such that $\phi(v)\neq 0$, so there exists $w$ such that $\beta_{left}(w)=\phi\neq 0$, etc.).

Comment: For $v \in V$ and $w \in W$, what is $\langle v \,|\, w \rangle$? What is a pairing? And, which book on Frobenius algebra are you using?

Comment: @azif00, thanks for your comment. Actually, my books give no explicit expression for $<v|w>$, I am reading Frobinous Algebras and 2D TQFT by joachim kock.